# Why does openCV image stitching work for images loaded in project but not dynamically loaded images

Tags: ios, image, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I have an application that stitches images using openCV and I save the images to my camera roll and to a location in the file system. When I pass those images in the file system as an array of UIImages in my file system, the stitching method does not work. However, when I take the images from my camera roll and download them to my computer and load them into my project through the copy bundle resources section, the stitching algorithm can easily stitch any of the images I put.

Is there a reason that this might happen and how can I fix it?

In [My Project](https://github.com/MichaelGofron/OpenCVStitch) I am loading the image array in the CVViewController and storing the images in the CameraViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I had accidentally been saving the images captured on the app to the same location thereby sending the stitching algorithm in OpenCV multiple instances of the same image.